# Grails validation errors disappear from service to controller

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

When I do custom rejectValue in a service method grails loses that error(s) between service method and return to controller. This seems to happen when updating a row instance, but not when creating one.

In service

```
def specialValidation(petInstance){
       if(petInstance.petType.requiresStateId && !petInstance.StateId){
           petInstance.errors.rejectValue('StateId','StateId required');
       }
       println petInstance.errors //shows 1 error
       return petInstance;

}
```

In controller

```
...
   petInstance.properties=params;
   petInstance=petService.specialValidation(petInstance);
   println petInstance.errors //shows 0 errors
```

How is the error being lost when the instance changes hands from service to controller?

Comment: Can you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be because of transactional service. Service opens separate transaction for each method and clears entities after method end. You can find this mentioned in [docs](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.4/guide/services.html#transactionsRollbackAndTheSession)(read the last paragraph of part )

I had the same problem. Than I've added `NotTransactional` annotation to validation method, and it helped. Errors were saved.

Answer (score 1):

Well I did something simular :

```
 orderService.validate(order, params)
 if (order.hasErrors()) {
      return render(view: 'create', model: [order: order])
}
```

In the Service I do some validation like this:

```
if (end.before(start)) { 
        order.errors.rejectValue("end", '', 'ERROR');
}
```

The different to yours is that i didn't set the errorCode but the message at itself, have a look at the rejectValue Methods:

```
void rejectValue(String field, String errorCode);
void rejectValue(String field, String errorCode, String defaultMessage);
```

You could also try to use the rejectValue method like me, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found you can also avoid this by using

```
 MyDomain.read(id)
```

instead of

```
MyDomain.get(id)
```